# MACD indicator is not working in highstock

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I'm trying to change graph indicators on a button click. I've integrated 4 indicators sma, boilinger band, ema and macd. First 3 are working but macd is not working.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zy003f7w/2/)

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  plotOptions: {
    candlestick: {
      color: '#66a6ff',
      upColor: '#3c68a7'
    },
    column: {
      color: '#D3D3D3'
    }
  },

  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 1
  },

  yAxis: [{
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -3
    },

    height: '70%',
    lineWidth: 2,
    resize: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }, {
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -3
    },

    top: '70%',
    height: '30%',
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2
  }],

  tooltip: {
    split: true
  },

  series: getSeries(coinFullName, coin, currency),
  credits: false
});

}
```

Here's the snippet you can search in fiddle:

```
if($("#indicatorType").val() == 'macd'){
    series.push({
        name:'MACD',
        type: 'macd',
        linkedTo: 'primary'
    });
}
```

Comment: I think all high,low,open,close should be non zero. check this http://jsfiddle.net/h1sm82yf/

Comment: Thanks. It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting.

I isolated demo with `MACD` here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/swc4sj36/

and it seems that the issue is related with this specific data. I created a new case in our bugtracker here:

- https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7788

Comment: Thank you. @Sebastian I have changed the data and now my issue is resolved.

Comment: At this moment it is workaround, but definately we need to fix the issue, especially that the problem is related with included EMA.